# How to identify parent component of a component uniquely in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I have a component called **Com1** and I have import that component inside of several components. My **Com1** component contain a button and when the button is clicked function triggered. Inside that function I want to print the parent component of my **Com1** component instance. How can I do that. Image below describe the scenario.

[image]

This is my component.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter',
  templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter.component.css']
})
export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(

  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onButtonClicked() {
    console.log("parent component");
  }

}
```

When the button clicked I want to print the parent component of my **Com1** component as `Com2`, `Com3` , `Com4`.

Comment: I doubt if you can do it from child, but a nice work around would be, on button click emit an event to parent and let parent log which component it is

Comment: Yeah.. but the problem is its not just console.log(). there is some workaround. its little bit complex. that why i asked just to console.log(). So its not possible to do inside of parent component. i must need to do that in child component itself.

Comment: Well then explain the whole scenario or else helping would be difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Pass the parent component name as input to your child component and use it there.

```
@Input parentName:string;
```

and in html

```
[parentName]="com2"
```